# Remove Default.css from Web Forms For Marketers in Sitecore

Tags: web, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Is there a way to remove default.css and /colors/default.css from a page with a web form for marketers form on it using sitecore?

I have found a few places suggest simply deleting the file, but then it is still outputting redundant code. I don't want to simply delete the contents of the file for the same reason.

I have found the forms folder in sitecore with the standard values seemingly telling the form to import default.css, but if I change it to blank or even another file, default is still there and nothing else shows up.

Answer (score 1):

You can open static method Sitecore.Forms.Core.Configuration.ThemeManager.RegisterCssScript in Sitecore.Forms.Core assembly via reflector. It seems that there is no simple way to remove adding this style reference.

You can remove this link in OnInit or OnLoad events handling as workaround.